# xcode always shows old version

Tags: xcode, temporary-files

I have developed a phonegap application with XCode. Most of the time I develop on Windows machine and debug with firebug. Now I want to transfer the app on my iphone and open the project-file with XCode. The code is up to date but when I click `run` to run the app in the simulator it shows a partly old version. Only the `index.html` seems to be old, the rest of the files show the actual status. If I delete the `index.html` the app should not work but it still runs.
I already clicked `clean` and pressed `shift+option cmd+k` to clean the temp files but that doesn't solve the problem.

**EDIT**

Fixed it a few seconds after posted this. There was a space in the `index.html` filename (`index .html`) and this caused xcode to use a old `index.html` (no idea where this is saved)

Comment: fixed it a few seconds after posted this, sry. :) there was a space in the index.html filename (index .html) and this caused xcode to use a old index.html (no idea where this is saved)

Comment: Might be good to post that as an answer.  Knowing that certain names cause problems is a good thing.

Comment: done, but i have to wait 2 days until i can mark it as the right answer :(

Comment: not constructive and was typo error in file name

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it a few seconds after posted this. There was a space in the index.html filename (index .html) and this caused xcode to use a old index.html (no idea where this is saved).